# How to resolve the error caused by the Eval() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eval is working fine with integral value but not for string. It is working for Integral value

```
from sys import argv
args=argv[1:]
b=0
for x in args:
a = eval(x)
# print(type(a))
b = b + a
print('Entered values sum is:',b)
```

Following is the error that I'm facing:

> python test.py 'surrender' 'pal' Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
>     a = eval(x)
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
> NameError: name 'surender' is not defined
> ```

Comment: please show us your error so we can diagnose the problem

Comment: @3NiGMa I added the error for your reference !

Answer (score 0):

When you run it, add extra quotes like this:

```
python test.py '"surrender"' '"pal"'
```

Otherwise python doesn't know it's a string ;). Also make sure to have b the type you want it to be (int or str). So instead of `b=0` use `b=''` so it can add strings.

Comment: I'm facing this issue now:  python test.py "'surende' 'pal'"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 32, in <module>
    b = b + a
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'